# React Native: Network Error while making Post Request with Axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm always getting a `TypeError: Network request failed` Error while making a post request with formdata through axios in react-native.
I tested the request in Postman and it works fine

EDIT: Something is really weird, because when I trigger the axios post request the first time, then it throws that network error, but the second time I trigger that, **everything works**

My Axios Post:

```
const registerComplete = async () => {
let data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', photo1);
    data.append('image', photo2);
    data.append('image', photo3);
    data.append('image', photo4);
    data.append('image', photo5);
    data.append('userid', userid);

    let config = {
      Authorization: UPLOAD_AUTH_HEADER,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    };
    axios
      .post(API_URL + 'multiple', data, {headers: config})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Example Content of photo1:

```
{"name": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_5ac884de-eafa-43de-9d18-c1c092716eda.jpg", "type": "image/jpg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.test/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_5ac884de-eafa-43de-9d18-c1c092716eda.jpg"}
```

My NestJs Backend:

```
@Post('multiple')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('image', 20, {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './files',
        filename: editFileName,
      }),
      fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
    }),
  )
  async uploadMultipleFiles(@UploadedFiles() files) {
    const response = [];
    files.forEach((file) => {
      const fileReponse = {
        originalname: file.originalname,
        filename: file.filename,
      };
      response.push(fileReponse);
    });
    return response;
  }
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: Can you tell me if you are testing the `axios` URL on your emulator/simulator/real device?

Comment: Yes I tested it on my own Device and on the emulator. The API_URL is my IP Adresse of my PC, where the Backend is running